# How should I save the state of an audio file when the user suspends my application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

In my app I need to play a 50 MB audio story.  If at about the 27 minute mark the user hits the home button, the sound pauses.  When they resume the application, the audio resumes where it left off.

I'm using AVAudioPlayer to play this audio, but I'm worried about keeping this large audio file in memory when my application goes to the background.  What would you recommend for minimizing the memory impact of saving / resuming state for an audio file like this?

Comment: I don't know AVAudioplayer very well, but does it let you seek to any position in the file and begin playback there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operating system will kill your app (and reclaim its memory) if necessary, so I wouldn’t be worried about Apple rejecting it on those grounds.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you stick with AVAudioPlayer for something of such size. One thing you can do is to put handling in your app delegate to free your audio in the applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning method. The OS will send that call if your app is backgrounded and it needs more heap memory and that way you can gracefully deal with the issue.

Presumably you just read the currentTime property when backgrounded and then set it when you want to continue your app. If you do this you could, potentially, just free up your memory on an interrupt and try to re-create your player when you wake back up, but I'd personally just stick with only freeing when you get the memory warning.

And as for OpenAL, it's great for short sounds that you want to play quickly, but I'd suggest you stay away from it for anything longer than just a couple of seconds, max.

Comment: Hello, the currentTime is a good idea but is there a specific code to handle this issue ? in addition what to do after save the currentTime make a release to AVAudioPlayer ?  Thanks

Comment: @Bobi-C - currentTime is simply a property.  Read it to gather the current playback time (which you could save to NSUserDefaults) and set it to seek playback forward to the correct location in the audio file.  As far as the audio data, simply release it and nil out the data property on the AVAudioPlayer.  This should free up the memory of the audio file, which you would then reload when your application becomes active again.  This all should be fairly trivial to implement.

Comment: When releasing allocated memory just ensure that your memory management is being handled correctly (simplest check is to run the app with the Leaks tool to see if your release/nil is leaking the memory) but if you are using an autorelease pool you should be able to just release & nil it as stated as long as you've not specifically retained it or done something else to increase the touch count for that chunk of memory.

Comment: where i should put  NSUserDefaults to save the currentTime when user click the home button ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use OpenAL: http://www.gamedev.net/reference/articles/article2008.asp

Then set AL_SEC_OFFSET (seconds offset) to the stored position in order to begin where the user left off.

Comment: i read a lot about OpenAl but i'm still a student and i can't understad OpenAl i used both and found the AudioToolbox and AVFoundation framework easier than OpenAl

Comment: OpenAL is extreme overkill for this situation.  Simply storing the playback position on exit and seeking to there on return using AVAudioPlayer will take much less time to implement.